# Yarn 2 / Webpack require.resolve "use" array of UseEntry fails to reference loader

Tags: webpack, yarnpkg, webpack-5, yarnpkg-v2

I'm trying to upgrade to yarn 2, and am running into a bit of a road block when it comes to "using" array based loaders and resolving properly.

Here is an excerpt from the previous working webpack configuration.

```
...
{
  test: /\.(gif|png|jpeg|jpg|svg)$/i,
  include: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/images"),
  use: [
   "file-loader",
   {
     loader: "image-webpack-loader",
     options: {
       mozjpeg: { progressive: true },
       gifsicle: { interlaced: true },
       optipng: { enabled: false },
       pngquant: { enabled: false }
     }
   }
 ]
},
...
```

Running `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/doctor` returns the following error message.

```
assets/webpack.common.js:33:14: Webpack configs from non-private packages should avoid referencing loaders without require.resolve
```

Line 33 column 14 is the opening bracket character for the 'use' key.

When I wrap the loader strings in a `require.resolve(...)` I get the same error from the yarn doctor command.

Does anyone have an idea why there is an issue resolving here? This should be completely fine based on the docs from webpack but I'm not certain which tool is having difficulty here.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleuse

Environment:
OSX: 10.15.7 (19H15) - Catalina

node -v: v15.3.0

yarn --version: 2.4.0

webpack: ~5.9.0

Comment: I found that error code here: https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration#before-we-start , it might be worth reading

Comment: I've read that error code in the docs and unfortunately it's not useful. Doing what is recommended does not address the problem. It looks like `require.resolve` does not work when you use multiple resolvers.

Comment: I believe this is just a Bug in `doctor` ... Logging an issue in the Berry Bug Tracker should resolve this. The check is here: https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/blob/6b9df772ac785f73e6d08f0fc8c3f1718f296671/packages/yarnpkg-doctor/sources/cli.ts#L97

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug in the `@yarnpkg/doctor`, the bug is located at this code block:
https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/blob/6b9df772ac785f73e6d08f0fc8c3f1718f296671/packages/yarnpkg-doctor/sources/cli.ts#L157-L159

```js
if (name === `use` || name === `loader`) {
  checkForUnsafeWebpackLoaderAccess(workspace, property.initializer, {configuration, report});
}
```

The code block above treats the values for properties `use` and `loader` as a reference to the loader, but it does not handle arrays, in your case `use` is an array.

The first naive shot to fix this inside the `@yarnpkg/doctor` is to change the block above to:

```js
if (name === `use` || name === `loader`) {
  if (property.initializer.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.ArrayLiteralExpression) {
    ts.forEachChild(property.initializer, childNode => {
    if (childNode.kind !== ts.SyntaxKind.ObjectLiteralExpression) {
        checkForUnsafeWebpackLoaderAccess(workspace, childNode, {configuration, report});
      }
    });
  } else {
    checkForUnsafeWebpackLoaderAccess(workspace, property.initializer, {configuration, report});
  }
}
```

The way this code block above handles array for `loader` and `use` properties is by visiting items and running doctor checks on each item which is not an object literal, object literals will be handled during recursion in `processNode` function. This special branch off for arrays is needed to treat non-object literal array items in a special way - as a loader references.

This is just one way how it can be implemented, another possible way is to remember that we are iterating inside `loader` and `use` arrays in `processFile` outer function local variables.